# filter row by successive conditions - group by

Tags: r, group-by

I have the following data frame:

```
df.temp <- tribble(
        ~ Case,
        ~ Operator,
        ~ Interval,
        ~ Value,

        "A","John","01-Blue",10,
        "A", "Cage","01-Blue",10,

        "A","John","02-Red",20,
        "A","Cage","03-Yellow",30,

        "A","John","04-Grey",37,
        "A","Cage","04-Grey",40,

        "A","Cage","05-Brown",55,
        "A","John","05-Brown",60,

        "A","Cage","05-Black",60,
        "A","Cage","05-Black",65,

        "B","John","01-Blue",10,

        "B","Cage","02-Red",10,
        "B","John","02-Red",20,

        "B","John","03-Yellow",30,

        "B","John","04-Grey",44,
        "B","Cage","04-Grey",40,

        "B","Cage","05-Brown",55,
        "B","Cage","05-Brown",60,

        "B","Cage","05-Black",60,
        "B","Cage","05-Black",63,
)
```

I'd like to create a column which indicate which rows keep which remove.

It should be going with this sequence and should be applied per Case:
- If there are duplicates in Interval (could be more than two) check if they have difference in Value 4 or more, then keep both 
- If difference is less or equal 3 and Intervals have different Operator then keep John, remove Cage 
- If there are duplicates in Interval with same Operator keep one with the smallest Value 
- If there are unique Intervals (no duplicates) keep whatever is available

I've tried something with nested ifelse statements but I've messed up to full fill all conditions :(

```
df.temp %>% group_by(Case) %>%
        arrange(Value) %>%
        mutate(Remove = ifelse (Operator == "Cage" &
                               (Interval == lag(Interval) | lead(Interval) == Interval) &
                               ((Value - lag(Value)) <= 3 |lead(Value) - Value <= 3),"remove","keep"))%>%
arrange(Case)
```

Desired output below.

```
Case  Operator Interval  Value Remove
   <chr> <chr>    <chr>     <dbl> <chr> 
 1 A     John     01-Blue      10 keep  
 2 A     Cage     01-Blue      10 remove

 3 A     John     02-Red       20 keep  

 4 A     Cage     03-Yellow    30 keep  

 5 A     John     04-Grey      37 keep  
 6 A     Cage     04-Grey      40 remove 

 7 A     Cage     05-Brown     55 keep  
 8 A     John     05-Brown     60 keep  

 9 A     Cage     05-Black     60 keep
10 A     Cage     05-Black     65 remove (more than 3 points diff, same Operator)

11 B     John     01-Blue      10 keep  

12 B     Cage     02-Red       10 keep
13 B     John     02-Red       20 keep  

14 B     John     03-Yellow    30 keep  

15 B     Cage     04-Grey      40 keep
16 B     John     04-Grey      44 keep  

17 B     Cage     05-Brown     55 keep  
18 B     Cage     05-Brown     60 remove

19 B     Cage     05-Black     60 keep
20 B     Cage     05-Black     63 remove
```

Thanks for any help in any direction!

Looks like I need a bit in addition to pick out cases with same operator and minimum value from matching pair but can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: Hi again - can you explain why line 6 (Cage 04-Grey) and 12 (Cage 02-Red) are remove? It looks like in your code you check rows before/after to see if `Value` changes by more/less than 3, but this is not described in your rules. Plus this may compare with different intervals (was that desired?). Just wanted to understand the logic there.

Comment: Hi @Ben, yes you are right - I use not use exact match but instead difference more than 3. That’s why line 6 should be removed, line 12 looks like a wrong one, should be keep. And no it shouldn’t look outside Interval, it should compare Values per Case, per Interval(could be more than two though). I’ll correct question.

Comment: Why in row 3 and 4 "02-Red " and "03-Yellow" are compared? According to your rule 1 `If there are duplicates in Interval (could be more than two) check if they have difference in Value`. Red and Yellow are not duplicates then why their difference matters ?

Comment: @RonakShah true, they are not compared, my typo, will correct

Comment: Thanks, you can check my answer below. I think row 15 and 16 should have "remove" and "keep" since it has operator "John" and "Cage".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `group_by` `Case` and `Interval` and apply the conditions using `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)

df.temp %>%
   group_by(Case, Interval) %>%
   mutate(Remove = case_when(
     #If there are duplicates in Interval check the difference in Value 4 
     #or more, then keep both
     n() > 1 & any(diff(Value) >= 4) & n_distinct(Operator) == 2 ~"keep", 
     #If difference is less or equal 3 and Intervals have different Operator
     #Keep John
     n_distinct(Operator) == 2 & all(diff(Value) <= 3) & Operator == "John"~"keep", 
     #and remove Cage
     n_distinct(Operator) == 2 & all(diff(Value) <= 3) & Operator == "Cage"~"remove",
     #If there are duplicates in Interval with same Operator 
     #keep one with the smallest Value
     n() > 1 & n_distinct(Operator) == 1 & Value == min(Value) ~ "keep",
     #and remove one which is not the smallest Value
     n() > 1 & n_distinct(Operator) == 1 & Value != min(Value) ~ "remove", 
     #keep rest of them
     TRUE ~"keep"))


# Case  Operator Interval  Value Remove
#   <chr> <chr>    <chr>     <dbl> <chr> 
# 1 A     John     01-Blue      10 keep  
# 2 A     Cage     01-Blue      10 remove
# 3 A     John     02-Red       20 keep  
# 4 A     Cage     03-Yellow    30 keep  
# 5 A     John     04-Grey      37 keep  
# 6 A     Cage     04-Grey      40 remove
# 7 A     Cage     05-Brown     55 keep  
# 8 A     John     05-Brown     60 keep  
# 9 A     Cage     05-Black     60 keep  
#10 A     Cage     05-Black     65 remove
#11 B     John     01-Blue      10 keep  
#12 B     Cage     02-Red       10 keep  
#13 B     John     02-Red       20 keep  
#14 B     John     03-Yellow    30 keep  
#15 B     John     04-Grey      44 keep  
#16 B     Cage     04-Grey      40 remove
#17 B     Cage     05-Brown     55 keep  
#18 B     Cage     05-Brown     60 remove
#19 B     Cage     05-Black     60 keep  
#20 B     Cage     05-Black     63 remove
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! need to read carefully about case_when () looks like very useful thing for me!